# Trying to get a simple ExtJS 4.2 XTemplate to work with simple store

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I'm very new to extjs and I'm trying to get a simple XTemplate to work. I have two cases below. #1 works fine. The generated output is: '**One, 1**' surrounded by the p tags. #2 doesn't work though. The output only produces the comma: '**,**' surrounded by the p tags. In short, I'm unable to deference/access the data from the store.

```
// 1. This one works
var data = {name: "One", age: "1"};
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
        '<tpl for".">',
            '<p>{name}, {age}</p>',
        '</tpl>'
);
var generatedHtml = tpl.apply(data);
console.log(generatedHtml);

// 2. This one doesn't work
var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
    fields: ["name", "age"],
    data: [
        {name: "One", age: "1"},
        {name: "Two", age: "2"}
    ]
});
var tpl2 = new Ext.XTemplate(
        '<tpl for".">',
            '<p>{data.name}, {data.age}</p>',
        '</tpl>'  
);
var generatedHtml2 = tpl2.apply(myStore);
console.log(generatedHtml2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realized I was missing the **=** after the **for**! When I put that in it worked.

Comment: yep, that does it. I missed that :)

Comment: thank you for taking a peek ... :) i spent a while looking at that before i found it. i cut/pasted the the first tpl (which worked) which sent me down the wrong path.